# Expire a record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rails-api

I have an ApiKey record in my Rails app. It has an expires_at datetime column.

I'm trying to use this callback to expire it:

```
before_find :expire_api_key
def expire_api_key
  if self.expired?
    self.destroy!  
  end
end
```

However, the first time I try to find an expired ApiKey, it still returns the key. Only if I call find again it'll raise `RecordNotFound`.

This is problematic because I can't let expired ApiKeys work.

Comment: There's no `before_find` callback, according to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), just an `after_find` callback.

Comment: Weird, because the method does fire. Anyway, it doesn't work with after_find either

Answer (score 2):

You can raise an error on your own:

```
if self.expired?
  self.destroy!
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
```